# Negative sign incorrect when finding determinant by applying Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

(I don't know how to make a matrix here, someone please correct it into a better format, thanks~)

So I'm applying the Gaussian Elimination to find the determinant for this matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&3\\
1&2&0\\
0&3&4\\
\end{pmatrix}$

So, I switched row $1$ and $2$: 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0\\
0&1&3\\
0&3&4\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then, add the multiple of $-3$ of row $2$ to the third row: $\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0\\
0&1&3\\
0&0&-5\\
\end{pmatrix}$

So the determinant I got is $-5$, however the answer key said it's $5$.  Some1 point out what I have done wrong?  Thank you!!

Comment: Try to click edit to look at the coding so you can try it next time you ask a question

Comment: I did, it surely is amazing how computers can do nowadays! Thanks! =p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you apply Gaussian Elimination to find the determinant, you have to multiply by $(-1)$ at the end for every row switches you have applied.

Comment: I knew i made a stupid mistake somewhere, thank you!